# Show that $f = ax + b$ a.e. $x \in [0, 1]$ if $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ whenever $\int_0^1 g(x) dx = \int_0^1 x g(x) dx = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f \in L^2([0, 1])$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx = 0$ for every $g \in C[0, 1]$ with $\int_0^1 g(x) dx = \int_0^1 xg(x) dx = 0$, show that $f(x) = ax + b$ a.e. $x \in [0, 1]$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I guess we may assume $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$ and so the question is reduced to showing $f(x) = f(1)x$ a.e.

But I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 3):

This is immedaite from basic Hilbert space theory. If $M=span \{1,x\}$ then it is given that $f \in (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$ so $f \in M$.

Comment: Ah you are right, I forgot $L^2$ is a Hilbert space and we can transform the problem into a Hilbert space problem.